# How To Cap My Fridge Water Line

Tags: plumbing

I wonder if someone could help me sort this issue out?

The water line to my refrigerator has no shutoff. I need to cap it, but it's setup so the threads of the waterline are connected to a nut on the copper piping - the water line is threaded into the nut on the copper line and tightened down. (see photo)

What can I buy to cap it off? I thought I could just buy a brass compression cap, but that's the wrong thing because there is nothing to screw it onto on the copper pipe. Also, I am not exactly sure what size I would need of whatever the solution is, so any guidance on that would be appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are caps available with internal threads, ans plugs with external threads, use whichever  fits.

It looks like you have compression nuts on both sides of a pipe nipple so either remove the nipple and use a plug or retain the nipple and use a cap with thread sealing tape.

Hollow plugs plugs like these, can be used with the existing compression nut to cap the pipe.
[image]

Alternatively a cap could be used to seal the end of the nipple

[image]

The presence of thread sealing tape indicate that the ferrule on the copper pipe is possibly damaged,  now would be a good time to replace that.

Instead of a plug or cap you could fit a valve there, you may find that to be convenient in the future.,

Comment: Thank you. That should do the trick! I appreciate the thorough response! This is a huge help!

Comment: Then accept the answer....